# JavaFX 8 How to set program icon to alert?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

How can I set program icon to alert without using `alert.initOwner()`?
Why without `initOwner`? It's because some alert must be shown before whole window is initialized, so there's no scene that I can put to `initOwner` function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can steal the [DialogPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#dialogPaneProperty) from an Alert instance, and add it to a regular Stage.  A Node can only be the root of one Scene at a time, so you need to replace the root of the Alert’s Scene first:

```
public class AlertWithIcon
extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION,
            "Are you sure you want to delete this item?",
            ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
        alert.setHeaderText("Delete Item");

        DialogPane pane = alert.getDialogPane();

        ObjectProperty<ButtonType> result = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        for (ButtonType type : pane.getButtonTypes()) {
            ButtonType resultValue = type;
            ((Button) pane.lookupButton(type)).setOnAction(e -> {
                result.set(resultValue);
                pane.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            });
        }

        pane.getScene().setRoot(new Label());
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

        Stage dialog = new Stage();
        dialog.setScene(scene);
        dialog.setTitle("Delete Item");
        dialog.getIcons().add(new Image("GenericApp.png"));

        result.set(null);
        dialog.showAndWait();

        System.out.println("Result is " + result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
public class AlertWithIcon
extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION,
            "Are you sure you want to delete this item?",
        ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);    
       alert.setHeaderText("Delete Item"); 
   ((Stage)alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()).getIcons().add(new image("GenericApp.png"));
    alert.showAndWait();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done:

```
// Get the Stage.
Stage stage = (Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();

// Add a custom icon.
stage.getIcons().stage.getIcons().add(new Image("images/logo_full3.png"));
```

There might be problem with the image reference above. But you can try to configure as long as it works. This is how I do (I use maven). Yours might be different if you are not using maven.

Full tutorial here: [Alert javafx tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)

Answer (score -1):

The correct implementation is following comments above:

```
// Get the Stage.
Stage stage = (Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();

// Add a custom icon.
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/logo_full3.png")));
```